# Setting up file geodatabase API

Tags: esri-geodatabase, visual-studio, file-geodatabase-api

Can someone point me to a guide for setting up the file geodatabase API?  I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012.

I can deal with writing and debugging the code - I just can't seem to figure out how to get all the files and folders in the right place so that things will compile.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit (Information on Errors):
I've downloaded the File Geodatabase API, extracted it to my (local) drive and opened the samples_VS2010.sln.  Since I just want to experiment with how the API works, I click on the compile/run button.  I get 18 errors:

```
Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBegin    referenced in function "void __cdecl    DrawCity(double,double,long,class std::basic_string<char,struct    std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)"    (?DrawCity@@YAXNNJV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)  C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display Error   2   error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol __imp_glClear referenced in function "void    __cdecl Display(void)" (?Display@@YAXXZ) C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display Error   3   error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol __imp_glClearColor referenced in function    main  C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display    Error    4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glColor3f    referenced in function "void __cdecl    DrawCity(double,double,long,class std::basic_string<char,struct    std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)"    (?DrawCity@@YAXNNJV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)    C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display Error   5   error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol __imp_glEnd referenced in function "void    __cdecl DrawCity(double,double,long,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class    std::allocator<char> >)"    (?DrawCity@@YAXNNJV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)    C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display Error   6   error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol __imp_glFlush referenced in function "void    __cdecl Display(void)" (?Display@@YAXXZ) C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display Error   7   error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol __imp_glLoadIdentity referenced in    function "void __cdecl Display(void)" (?Display@@YAXXZ)  C:\kav\FGDB    API\samples\Display\Display.obj  
Display Error   8   error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol __imp_glOrtho referenced in function "void    __cdecl Display(void)" (?Display@@YAXXZ) C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display Error   9   error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol __imp_glRasterPos2f referenced in function    "void __cdecl DrawCity(double,double,long,class    std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class    std::allocator<char> >)"    (?DrawCity@@YAXNNJV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display Error   10  error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol __imp_glVertex3f referenced in function    "void __cdecl DrawCity(double,double,long,class    std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class    std::allocator<char> >)"    (?DrawCity@@YAXNNJV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)    C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display Error   11  error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol glutInit referenced in function    main    C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display    Error    12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol    glutInitDisplayMode referenced in function main    C:\kav\FGDB    API\samples\Display\Display.obj  
Display Error   13  error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol glutInitWindowSize referenced in function    main  C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display    Error    14  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glutMainLoop    referenced in function main   C:\kav\FGDB    API\samples\Display\Display.obj  
Display Error   15  error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol glutCreateWindow referenced in function    main    C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display    Error    16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glutDisplayFunc    referenced in function main    C:\kav\FGDB    API\samples\Display\Display.obj  
Display Error   17  error LNK2019:    unresolved external symbol glutBitmapCharacter referenced in function    "void __cdecl DrawCity(double,double,long,class    std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class    std::allocator<char> >)"    (?DrawCity@@YAXNNJV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) C:\kav\FGDB API\samples\Display\Display.obj 
Display Error   18  error LNK1120: 17    unresolved externals   C:\kav\FGDB    API\samples\\bin64\Display.exe   Display
```

Comment: What's the error that you are actually getting?

Comment: glutInitWindowSize , ... are functions from OpenGL. Make sure you link to these libraries correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio Express 2012, then you may want to try it with the 2012, not the 2010, solution.  I don't know if that is actually your problem though.

In the 2012 solution that I have used, there is this comment at the top of Display.cpp:

```
// Uses glut to display a point feature class. To build this program you will have to 
// install glut and adjust the project settings or make file to reference your install.
```